# How to make a QOTD server or similar

Tags: terminal, port, protocol

QOTD ("Quote of the Day") is a protocol that can be open on servers by default on port 17. I have googled and googled and for some reason there is pretty much no information on how to make a server, that when connected to on port 17, could return a quote using QOTD.

In fact, the QOTD server could be used as a practical way of showing and sending data in a bash-readable form if it could handle large amounts of text and if it were not prone to the "ping-pong" attack. [Wikipedia- QOTD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QOTD)

This attack consists of the qotd server sending replies to requests from another computer, and when the requests are too many, then the server will crash (a simple DoS attack)

Here is an example of a QOTD server (run this in terminal on a mac or linux machine)

```
  nc shairosenfeld.com 17
```

Is there a way to make a sort of QOTD type server where the requests could be limited in the amount per minute, or if spammers for replies could be banned (like denyhosts for ssh)? Does anyone have a linux example, because I have looked with no luck.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It appears to be quite trivial to write a QOTD application.  I'm not a python programmer, but a proof-of-concept server would be:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from socket import *
myHost = ''
myPort = 17

s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)    # create a TCP socket
s.bind ( (myHost, myPort) )
s.listen (5)

while 1:
  connection, address = s.accept() 
  connection.send("echo Hello World\n")
  connection.close()
```

(Which needs to run as root, of-course - because the port is less then 1024)

You could then do some limiting with IPTABLES to limit the number of connections -
Something like:

```
/sbin/iptables  -A INPUT -p tcp --syn --dport 17 -m connlimit --connlimit-above 3 -j REJECT
```

(See [here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/iptables-connection-limits-howto/) for more options for connection limiting on iptables)

Answer (score 5):

Creating a command line QOTD server is trivial if you have netcat and fortune installed:

```
# nc -lk -p 17 -e fortune
```

Some versions of netcat may not have -e enabled, in which case use the busybox version, which does:

```
# busybox nc -lk -p 17 -e fortune
```